# metodo reconstrutor classe javascript?

Tags: javascript

Eu estou planejando uma classe carta:

```
class Carta {
    constructor (el) {
        // propriedades imutaveis
        this.el = el;
    }
    // metodos
    reconstrutor () {
        // propriedades mutaveis
    }
    isManilha () {

    }
    desenhar () {

    }
    apagar () {

    }
    jogar () {

    }
}
```

Dentro do construtor eu guardo `el` que e um elemento html. E um jogo de cartas entao a cada rodada eu poderia apagar os objetos antigos e instanciar novos com novas propriedades, mas o `el` teria que ser passado novamente. Entao seria mais correto usar um metodo reconstrutor para apenas alterar as propriedades necessarias ou isso seria uma gambiarra?

Comment: Nem sei o que deseja, mas imagino ser pelo menos invencionice.

Comment: era exatamente o que eu queria saber, saber se estou no caminho certo ou nao e ja vi que nao, isso que da ter php como primeira linguagem.

Comment: Se o objeto carta será "reinstânciado" - uma nova carta, penso que poderia utilizar somente o construtor. A não ser que somente propriedades da mesma carta será alterado, por exemplo, ela ser manilha num certo momento e não ser mais em outro momento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ideia de herança em classes faz o que procuras. Em vês de teres esse "reconstrutor" tens duas alternativas:

`#1`- Se fôr só `el` que muda, ou outros parâmetros que podem ser passados em variáveis então usa a mesma classe mas passa-lhe somente novos argumentos:

```
var A = new Carta('A', 'Joker', etc...);
```

`#2`- Se queres ter funcionalidade diferente, mas usando grande parte do código de outra classe podes usar `extends`, que no fundo é uma cópia da outra classe onde podes sobre-escrever métodos:

```
classe Joker extends Carta {
    constructor(el){
        super(el); // <- aqui chamas o construtor de Carta passando `el`.
    }

    desenhar () {
        // aqui podes escrever lógica que é só do Joker
        // os outros métodos serão os mesmos, mas este vai substituir
        // o método desenhar da classe Carta
    }

}
```